# How to style image paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**SCENARIO:** I am taking over for a web developer who left a mess of a website in my hands. Each image on the website (thousands) is wrapped in an anchor tag that takes it the user to the image's own path:

```
<a href="http://www.websitename.com/image_path.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.websitename.com/image_path.jpg" />
</a>
```

This is your typical web image path page: image is full-size and in the top left corner with white space filling the rest of the page. The header does not appear to have the dynamic header information that exists for the rest of the website.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to style this page? How can I force a stylesheet into this header? Or is this impossible? If it is impossible, is there any hacky way of hijacking the anchor tag that wraps each image? Maybe using jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

(Note that there are probably hundreds of different lightboxes, so you should research them and find something that you will fancy).

Alternatively you could redirect the request at server (apache/nginx) level and redirect the image path to some script that would style it.

Comment: How about the redirect request option? This seems like a good way of bring styling/customization beyond the lightbox.

Comment: How would I go about creating a redirect request for the server?

Comment: Do you use apache or nginx?

Comment: The lightbox option is good if you don't want the user to leave the page - so it just creates closable popup - also handy if you have multiple pages as user can go through them.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2.27. Lightbox pop-ups would be create if I can somehow override the anchor link immediately redirecting the page. I've been trying to create a JavaScript effect that occurs on clicking the image, but the redirect always happens too.

Comment: Are you using event.preventDefault()?